# How do I make svn ignore unversion files only in my working copy?

Tags: svn

duplicate: [Ignore SVN ignore... possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398/ignore-svn-ignore-possible)

---

Suppose my working copy is littered with unversioned files that I don't want to delete. I want svn to ignore these files, but I do *not* want to add them to the ignore list, because I don't want to pollute other people's working copy with my ignore list. Is this possible in svn?

Clarification: I'm not sure why, but people keep advising me to edit my global configs; however, this is *not* what I'm what I'm looking for. What I want to do is target specific files in a particular working copy. Is this even possible??

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the [user configuration file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2) can contain the `global-ignores` option which is exactly what you're looking for.

The location of this file varies by platform. From the documentation:

> On Unix-like systems, this area appears as a directory named .subversion in the user's home directory. On Win32 systems, Subversion creates a folder named Subversion, typically inside the Application Data area of the user's profile directory (which, by the way, is usually a hidden directory). However, on this platform the exact location differs from system to system, and is dictated by the Windows registry.

Comment: Does this apply to all my working copies? What if I only want the ignores to apply to one?

Comment: then you need to use the property svn:ignore

Comment: Peter, don't I have to commit svn:ignore? I don't want the ignore to get pushed to the repo, where my teammates will pull down the svn:ignore's that I set.

Comment: You don't *have* to commit the svn:ignore property, that is you could set it on your working copy and never actually commit it. This will be awkward to manage, however.

Comment: Greg, yes it would. It kind if defeats the purpose, since I'd then have to ignore the svn:ignore property.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, you can go in TortoiseSVN's settings (Right Click > TortoiseSVN > Settings).

In the General Tab, Subversion Group, add a lone asterisk (`*`) to the Global Ignore Pattern option.

Comment: Worked for me (simple)

Answer (score 0):

In your private subversion config file for the repository, set the global-ignores flag, like this:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = *.class *.o
```

Comment: on Windows (2000/XP) this file can be fond under 
%APPDATA%\Subversion\config

Comment: or in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\Miscellany\global-ignores

Comment: Seems like those configs apply to all working copies on my system. I want to set ignores on a specific working copy.