# Symbolic link in svn working copy for a switched directory

Tags: svn, switch-statement, symlink, working-copy

I work on several (2-20) projects of non-shared-ancestry in a single repo, that share common resources of GBs of binary data stored in the repository at only a single place. These projects utilize `svn switch` to map their appropriate folder to the single svn URL where they share the binary data.

I want to do the same in my working copies when more than one is checked out, thus avoiding redownloading the same GBs of binary data I already have.

(Note: Another bad news is that the projects also utilize an svn 1.7 executable in order to modify themselves.)

## what I did

What I've done is checking out *project A*, do the switch -es; then check out *project B*, but instead of regular switch, do `svn switch --set-depth=empty --ignore-ancestry http://foobar`, so this working copy of *project B* knows where it should point to. Then, I did `mv foobar old_foobar` and `mklink /D foobar ../project_A/foobar`. (1)

## the problem now

The problem is now that if I do `svn status` in the wc with the symbolic link, it lists all the files in "foobar " as non-versioned (as `?` status).

I also use TortoiseSVN and it shows the icon overlay as yellow triangular "!" (meaning perhaps confilcted?), but I have no actual conflict (nor tree conflict) in `svn status` and if I do `svn up` in "foobar", it says that it is up-to-date.

## constraints

The binary file containers do not change very often and even if they do, the changes are usually backward-compatible. Thus it is not a problem (for me, at least) that the working copy has a wrong idea about the file version in them.

I should *not* change the project or repo structure as I am not allowed to do that "officially".

**I use svn 1.7** and since the projects actually utilize a self-contained svn executable binary for work on themselves, I would like to stick to that if possible.

## question

Is there a way to utilize symbolic links (or anything else) in order to avoid duplicating the same GBs of data on my hard drive? (Also avoiding downloading it if possible.)

---

(1): I'm on Windows; for easyness, let's say the that *in my file system*, folders "project_B" and "project_A" are neighbours ie. share a single common ancestor and that folder foobar is top level in both projects.

Answer (score 1):

We have a situation where multiple projects may be nested inside each other.

The solution we used might work well for you;

1. For a project, check it out of the repository as normal.
2. Create a `svn:ignore` entry for the path that will contain the data, and make sure that path isn't tracked.
3. Check out the data to that path.
4. For additional projects, do step 1 and 2, but create a symlink instead.

Now all your projects will just ignore those extra files, but you can still manage the data through svn.

Yes, it means you'll need to remember to `svn update && svn update data/` to be sure your project is completely up to date, but it's not much of a hassle.

Comment: Hm, can `svn:ignore` be stored in the *working copy* **only**, in this solution? Uncommitted to the *repository*? (Because I should not change the working process of my [hundreds of] coworkers.)

Comment: I learn that there is a per-user ignore setting, that may be suitable one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398/ignore-svn-ignore-possible

Comment: Hundreds of coworkers? Wow.
Would it be worth proposing this as an org-wide solution, then?

I think the `global-ignores` directive might be a viable solution. Even if you have other projects with the same folder name, (that *should* be part of the repository) once you explicitly add them they'll work as normal.